Exact amount of equations needed to describe the image under the Veronese Embedding
I have a question on the Veronese embedding:
As you may now, the image of $\mathbb{P}_n$ under the Veronese embedding of degree $d$ for $n,d \in \mathbb{N}$ is defined by all equations of the form $X_{\mu}X_{\nu}=X_{\kappa}X_{\lambda}$ where $\mu,\nu,\kappa,\lambda$ are tuples in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}^{n+1}$ with the sum of their entries being $d$. Or in other words: we need all possible unique equations of tuples $\mu + \nu= \kappa + \lambda$. So at it‘s core, counting these is a combinatorics problem.
Does anyone here know how many (unique) of these equations there are exactly? I haven‘t found anything on the internet regarding that, so I basically wasted the past 4 days searching for a formula. Here is a table for small n,d that i created with a small c++ program. If you want to try it out: https://github.com/ChristusKistus/Veronese_tuples/blob/main/veronese_short.cpp
One thing that i am pretty sure is true, is that for $d=2$ there are exactly
${{n+1}\choose{2}}+1\choose{2}$, and interestingly for $d=3$ there are exactly
${{{n+1}\choose{2}}+1\choose{2}}$ $ {n+2}\choose{2}$ equations.
I would be very thankful for any contributions or ideas, since this question has been living rentfree in my head for 4 days.
Thank you!

How far off are those values from the naive (co-)dimension-count?

by naive codimension-count you mean ${N}\choose{2}$? (${n+d}\choose{d}$ is very far off very quickly) for small n,d its not too bad. But for example with n=d=6 both of these numbers are just way too small…
